# Hibernate Predicate SelectAll

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api, predicate, spring-data-jpa, selectall

I'm using Spring Data JPA with a specification to select rows out of table if the user has selected certain filters:

public interface Specification {
  Predicate toPredicate(Root root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb);
}

How do I create a predicate which will return everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented, [conjunction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#conjunction%28%29) with zero conjuncts is true. Such a predicate can be created as follows:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb ...
Predicate conjunction = cb.conjunction();
```

When opposite is needed, that is task for [disjunction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#disjunction%28%29) (with zero disjuncts it is false):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb ...
Predicate disjunction = cb.disjunction();
```

Disjunction without disjunct typically generates something like 1=0 to SQL query.